# How can I scale up a SVG without remaining sharp in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: svg, transform, scale, blur

I have a SVG with a lot of circles that translate upward to create a bubbling effect. On scroll, this SVG scales up 15x. In Safari, the circles become blurry on scale, but in Chrome and Firefox they stay sharp. I found a lot of questions asking how to get Safari to make them sharp as well, but I want the opposite. I need the circles to get blurry when scaling, mainly because the performance on Safari is much better, but also the blurriness gives it a nice depth of field effect.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a requirement that it must be SVG? It would be much easier to simply convert the SVG file to PNG and use that, instead of figuring out how to implement a mechanism that makes the SVG blurry.

Comment: Add a gaussian blur filter.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Thanks for responding. I tried it with PNGs, but the performance was worse than with svgs.

Comment: @Tijgerbrood I suspect that performance will take a greater hit, if the SVG's will have to be rendered as blurry on the client. Can you elaborate on why you want them blurry?

Comment: @LarsKristensen Initially I didn't necessarily want them blurry, but that is just how Safari seems to render the scaling. When I was testing in Chrome and Firefox the performance was much worse, so I suspected that the reason for that was because of the difference in rendering the scaled SVG. I noticed in those browsers that the circles remained sharp. That's mainly the reason why I want Chrome and Firefox to render in the same way as Safari, to get the same performance. I now added 1 perspective to the div and it renders the same as Safari, but the performance is still much worse sadly.